# What does animation:none do exactly?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I've got an HTML element here with this starting style:
   `transition: transform 2s;`

First, it is **animated** (it rotatesX) via a class that is added on click. On the next click, another class is added that adds a **transform3d** that should move the element vertically and this should take 2 seconds as per the rule above.

The **transform3d** doesn't take effect unless I add this rule to the element: `animation: none` as well. I am confused on what `animation: none` actually does. Are there complications with transforming an element that has had an animation applied to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`animation: none` sets all `animate-*` properties to their initial value:

```css
animation-name: none;
animation-duration: 0s;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-play-state: running;
```

The problem is that your element has an animation which affects its `transform` property. Therefore, when you modify its static `transform`, you don't see the change because it's overridden by the animation.

Then, if you remove the animation, you see the change in `transform`.

This is unrelated to transforms, it would happen with any property, like `color`:

```css
div {
  animation: color-anim 1s infinite;
}
@keyframes color-anim {
  from { color: red }
  to { color: blue }
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('div').style.color = '#fff'">Make white</button>
<button onclick="document.querySelector('div').style.animation = 'none'">Remove animation</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I forgot that my rotateX animation was actually animating a transform. However, in my case, at the time the **transform3d** is applied, the rotateX animation has already finished (in contrast to your example). I would have expected the original transform to be overridden if the animation is done?

Comment: Most probably you have a fill-mode forwards.